# Saving the content in prototype cells

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have the following problem. I have a tableviewcontroller & a viewcontroller.
Tableviewcontroller has a prototype cell which has a label on it, viewcontroller has two buttons "ok" & " "failed".

Usecase: user presses on a cell from tableview and gets redirected to Viewcontroller. He then presses on one of the two buttons this => in text from label from cell being changed into something.

Ok so far this work just fine for any cell i do this in, but when user scrolls trough the table view(off view then on view again) the cells get re-used and the label is set to default again.

What should i do to save them? I'm quite new to developing and i have no idea in which direction should i go from here.

Comment: Why don't you start off by showing us the code you have so far.

Comment: Tad bit late on this, but forgot i posted this question sorry. So what i did was: have a property array of tableview controller, have a method that loads objects into array. Call this method on view did load always.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly:
**You should modify your table view data source array after press button in ViewController.**

---

Example of press button handler in ViewController

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    self.items[indexPath.row] = sender.titleLabel.text; //ok or failed
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

`self.items` is data source array of your TableViewController

`indexPath` is indexPath of pressed cell

---

Example of TableViewController table view (it's not a real code but it should work)

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return items.count;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 50.0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Reuse or init cell...

    cell.textLabel.text = items[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MYViewController *viewController = [[MYViewController alloc]init];
    viewController.items = items;
    viewController.indexPath = indexPath;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **cellForRowAtIndexPath:** write the code as below 
`static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Reuse identifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
// add text to your label here
    return cell;` 
 and do not try to add label in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` create a label in Xib or Storyboard.